# display a .txt file with arraylist in java

Tags: java

I build this code with the help of this site (mostly copy pest). It's working for me, but I have some questions. The code is:

```
package dic;


import java.io.*;

import java.util.*;
public class MainDic {
    private List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    public String[] readOriginalFile(String filename) throws IOException      
    {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filename);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        String line = null;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(line);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        return lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        MainDic call = new MainDic();
        String filename = "dictionaryTXT.txt";
        String[] lines = call.readOriginalFile(filename);
        System.out.println("______ORIGINAL DOCUMENT______\n");
        for (String line : lines) {  
            System.out.println(line);       
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand these lines:

1. `public String[] readOriginalFile(String filename) throws IOException`
2. `return lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);`
3. `String[] lines = call.readOriginalFile(filename);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand these lines:
>
> 1. public String[] readOriginalFile(String filename) throws IOException
> 2. return lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
> 3. String[] lines = call.readOriginalFile(filename);

Well let's break these down starting with:

**1.**

```
public String[] readOriginalFile(String filename) throws IOException
```

This is just the header for the method `readOriginalFile`.  It is a `public` method meaning everyone can see it.  It returns an array of String (`String[]`).  And it may `throw` an exception called `IOException`.  Read more about that [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html).

**2.**

```
return lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
```

This takes the `File` object called `lines` and turns it the lines of the file into an array of Strings (`String[]`).

**3.**

```
String[] lines = call.readOriginalFile(filename);
```

This is just creating an instance of a String array by calling the method written above (`readOriginalFile`).

I highly recommend reading a [Java methods tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_methods.htm).

Answer (score 1):

1) A method signature, returning a `String array` called `readOriginalFile` with a parameter of the file name to be read. It `throws` an `IOException` if there is any error in processing the file, instead of `catching` any potential exceptions

2) Takes the input line, converts it into a `String array` and returns it from the method

3) Calls the method defined in `1`, taking the `String array` that is returned in question `2` and assigns it to a new `String array`

Does that clarify?

Considering this is a "copy pest" job, I think you should look at the language basics... such as a HelloWorld example. Start at the sun tutorials

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html

And

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html